# How can I use `add-to-list` to add multiple elements to a list value of a variable?

Tags: variables, list

Is this the way to use `add-to-list` with multiple entries?

```lisp
      (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist 
         '(("\\.f\\'" . fortran-mode)
           ("\\.F\\'" . fortran-mode)
           ("\\.f90\\'" . f90-mode)
           ("\\.f95\\'" . f90-mode)
           ("\\.f03\\'" . f90-mode)
           ("\\.f08\\'" . f90-mode)))
```

If not, how can I do so?

Comment: When you try it in your `*scratch*` buffer, what does `auto-mode-alist` look like afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The doc tells you that `add-to-list` adds a single element.

You can do what you want with this, for example:

```lisp
(defun add-list-to-list-var (list-var new-elements &optional append compare-fn)
  "Like `add-to-list', but add multiple elements NEW-ELEMENTS, in order."
  (interactive)
  (setq new-elements  (if append new-elements (reverse new-elements)))
  (let* ((val  (symbol-value list-var))
         (lst  (if append (reverse val) val)))
    (dolist (elt new-elements)
      (cl-pushnew elt lst :test compare-fn))
    (set list-var (if append (nreverse lst) lst)))
  (symbol-value list-var))
    
;; Check it:
(setq bar '("a" "b"))

(setq foo '("1" "2" "b" "4" "5"))
(add-list-to-list-var 'foo bar)                   ; ("a" "b" "1" "2" "b" "4" "5")

(setq foo '("1" "2" "b" "4" "5"))
(add-list-to-list-var 'foo bar 'APPEND)           ; ("1" "2" "b" "4" "5" "a" "b")

(setq foo '("1" "2" "b" "4" "5"))
(add-list-to-list-var 'foo bar nil #'string=)     ; ("a" "1" "2" "b" "4" "5")

(setq foo '("1" "2" "b" "4" "5"))
(add-list-to-list-var 'foo bar 'APPEND #'string=) ; ("1" "2" "b" "4" "5" "a")
```